# Insertar fecha y hora actual entabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Se creo la siguiente tabla, solicito poder insertar la fecha y hora actual en la que se realice el proceso

```
  create table "informix".ventas_saldos
  (
    f_inicial date not null ,
    f_final date not null ,
    c_almacen varchar (250),
    sw_costo smallint,
    sw_consulta smallint,
    usuario char(30) not null,
    sw_genera_consulta smallint,
    ts_creacion datetime year to fraction(3)
    default current year to fraction(3)
  );
```

he intentado hacerlo de diferente formas.

```
INSERT INTO ventas_saldos(f_inicial,f_final,c_almacen,sw_costo,sw_consulta,usuario,sw_genera_consulta,ts_creacion) values ('15/06/2017','15/06/2017','7,1',0,0,'ct060901',1,sysdate()) ;

INSERT INTO ventas_saldos(f_inicial,f_final,c_almacen,sw_costo,sw_consulta,usuario,sw_genera_consulta,ts_creacion) values ('15/06/2017','15/06/2017','7,1',0,0,'ct060901',1,now()) ;

INSERT INTO ventas_saldos(f_inicial,f_final,c_almacen,sw_costo,sw_consulta,usuario,sw_genera_consulta,ts_creacion) values ('15/06/2017','15/06/2017','7,1',0,0,'ct060901',1,CURDATE()) ;
```

pero en las tres opciones me genera el siguiente error:

> 674: Routine (sysdate) can not be resolved.

Comment: Hola.. php en este caso no me parece una etiqueta valida (no veo nada de php). respecto del valor que estas pasando a ts_creacion, entre parentesis no tiene que ir la misma precision que tiene el campo?

Answer (score 2):

Ya fue solucionado la situación. no estaba teniendo el tipo de dato

```
INSERT INTO ventas_saldos(
    f_inicial,
    f_final,
    c_almacen,
    sw_costo,
    sw_consulta,
    usuario,
    sw_genera_consulta,
    ts_creacion
) values (
    '15/06/2017',
    '15/06/2017',
    '7,1',
    0,
    0,
    'ct060901',
    1,
    curren`t
);
```

Comment: Por favor, márcala como aceptada :)